# Reclassify text in span as different IClassifierProvider

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

I am writing an extension for Visual Studio to allow the text within certain html attributes to be colorized like JavaScript/TypeScript. Is there a way to run just the content of the attribute using a different `IClassifier` or `IClassifierProvider`? In the example html below, the two attributes would in this case be run through the `IClassifierProvider` for the JavaScript/TypeScript `ContentType`

```html
<div v-for="item in list">
   <span v-if="item.prop == true">
</div>
```

Comment: Will this helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/colors-and-styling-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#from-managed-code

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT unfortunately, it does not. It has nothing to do with IClassifier.